# Update Dell Latitude BIOS with "dd" command rather than "UNetbootin"

Tags: dd, bios

I'm doing these [instructions](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN171755/en). I cannot use `UNetbootin`, therefore I'm trying `dd` command instead:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/fdbasecd.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=10M
```

After `dd`, the filesystem of bootable USB is `iso9660` and when I mount it, it says:

```
$sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/cdrom
mount: /dev/sdc is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

Due to being read-only, it is not possible to do this step of the [instructions](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN171755/en):

> After this operation is complete, copy the BIOS exe file to the USB storage device.

Apparently there is no problem with copying files to bootable USB when it is created with `UNetbootin`. However, I've created bootable USB with `dd` and I don't know how to copy BIOS exe file into it.

Is there any solution or any alternative command-line method.

Answer (score 0):

I could update Dell Latitude BIOS with `dd` command by following these two links:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS Under section: Upgrading with a FreeDOS USB drive
- http://www.chtaube.eu/computers/freedos/bootable-usb/

Steps I did are straight forward. First download and unzip:

```
bunzip2 FreeDOS-1.1-memstick-3-30M.img.bz2
```

Then run `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=FreeDOS-1.1-memstick-3-30M.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Then copy BIOS executable into USB (note that even though we used `dd` command, USB is writable and have a partition):

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
sudo cp D820_A10.EXE /media/usb/
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

While rebooting, press F12, and then go to `FreeDOS without loading drivers`. Then your are in `C:\>` and `dir` command shows the BIOS executable, so just run it with `D820_A10.EXE` and the rest is just the update process after which it reboots automatically and it can be verified that BIOS is updated.